# How do you close a GDK app when your deep in an activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-gdk

My GDK app starts by opening a standard Activity that overrides onCreateOptionsMenu and inflates a basic menu.xml.  You click an item then it calls startActivity with the intent of the next activity.  After a few of these activities I want the last activity to present a menu option to close the application.  However everything I tried simply kills the activity, not the application.  What's the right way to close an application that's not being started by a service?

Here's what I've tried:

```
finish();
process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

All of these simply close the current activity and show the activity behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out a solution.  I added this to each activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

So now when I call finish on the last one the application closes.  Not sure if this is the best thing to do but it works.